# How to reduce Flutter expansionTile height

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, size, tile

I want to reduce the height of an expansionTile,

I have tried [ConfigurableExpansionTile](https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile) but it doesn't support null safety so I can't use it in my project.

I have also wrapped my **ExpansionTile** in **ListTileTheme** as such :

```
return ListTileTheme(
      dense: true,
      child: ExpansionTile(
```

It reduce the height but still not enough for me.

Thanks for helping if you have a solution.

Comment: You can wrap with `SizedBox` and control height based on state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know about ExpansionTile but you can use [ExpandablePanel](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable), which can serve your purpose and you can easily custom the heights of the widgets. Also it supports null-safety.

```
ExpandablePanel(
theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
headerAlignment:
    ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
//tapBodyToExpand: true,
//tapBodyToCollapse: true,
hasIcon: false,
),
header: Expandable(
collapsed: buildCollapsed(), // widget header when the widget is Collapsed
   expanded: buildExpanded(), // header when the widget is Expanded
),
 collapsed: Container(), // body when the widget is Collapsed, I didnt need anything here. 
 expanded:  expandedColumn() // body when the widget is Expanded
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, works well !

Comment: Btw, is there an equivalent of onExpansionChanged of ExpansionTile in ExpandablePanel so that I can call a function when expanding the tile ?

Comment: You can call function by using any onTap/onPressed widget like ListTile/InkWell etc in your buildCollapsed/buildExpanded/expandedColumn widget according to your need.