# when expansion tile is expanded it removes textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter app i'm using `ExpansionTile` inside of a `Stack` widget. and below the expansion tile there is a `TextFormField`. so whenever i expand the tile the text field is removed but it will never re-appear again.

my tree is BottomSheeet -> Container -> Stack -> (here i ) -> [ExpansionTile , TextFormField].

Please, i know it's bulky... but check it out

below is my expansion tile

```
return Column(
      children: [
        ExpansionTile(
          initiallyExpanded: isExpand,
          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
            isExpand = value;
          },
          childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.04),
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
            radius: height * 0.02,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  imageUrl: url,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => const BlurHash(
                    hash: "LLGj~e}sQmn\$={aLS3tRMJS2b^X8",
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          title: Text(name),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.01,
              ),
              Text(
                doc['comment'],
                maxLines: 3,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.005,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(time),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        isExpand = true;
                      },
                      child: const Text("reply")),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          trailing: const SizedBox(),
          children: [
            FirestoreListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("posts")
                    .doc(id)
                    .collection("comments")
                    .doc(doc.id)
                    .collection("replies")
                    .orderBy("repliedAt"),
                emptyBuilder: (context) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text("no replies"),
                  );
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, snap) {
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("users")
                          .doc(snap['repliedBy'])
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapper) {
                        String url1 = '';
                        String name1 = '';
                        late String time1 = '';
                        if (snapper.hasData) {
                          url1 = snapper.data!['photoUrl'];
                          name1 = snapper.data!['name'];
                          Timestamp time2 = snap['repliedAt'];
                          DateTime date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
                              time2.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
                          time1 = timeago.format(date);
                        }
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
                                radius: height * 0.02,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                      imageUrl: url1,
                                      placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                          const BlurHash(
                                        hash: "LLGj~e}sQmn\$={aLS3tRMJS2b^X8",
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ),
                              title: Text(name1),
                              subtitle: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height * 0.01,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    snap['reply'],
                                    maxLines: 3,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height * 0.005,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(time1),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider()
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                }),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.01),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
                          radius: height * 0.015,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                imageUrl: FirebaseAuth
                                    .instance.currentUser!.photoURL!,
                                placeholder: (context, url) => const BlurHash(
                                  hash: "LLGj~e}sQmn\$={aLS3tRMJS2b^X8",
                                ),
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: width * 0.02,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints:
                                BoxConstraints(maxHeight: height * 0.03),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _replyController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "reply..."),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: width * 0.02,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // if (_formKey
                              //     .currentState!
                              //     .validate()) {
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection("posts")
                                  .doc(id)
                                  .collection("comments")
                                  .doc(doc.id)
                                  .collection("replies")
                                  .doc()
                                  .set({
                                "repliedBy":
                                    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
                                "reply": _replyController.text,
                                "repliedAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                              });
                              _replyController.text = '';
                              _replyController.clear();
                              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                              // }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "REPLY",
                              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
        Divider()
      ],
    );
```

and below the tile is just a textformfield wrapped in a Form and Positioned widget.

Comment: Personal suggestion, instead of using expansionTile you can use ExpandablePanel, cause I find it more managable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70696003/11445727
Hope this helps

Comment: can you provide the simplified version of your code so we can just copy paste and run?